How can we report validity on input in datatable
We have a component that extends lightning datatable and adds custom cell types. Those types contain lightning-input and lightning-select.
How can we call reportValidity() on those inputs?
What we've tried so far:

Messaging Service - works however I don't like this approach from design perspective
querySelector - can't select it from parent component level, nor from datatable component level. The deepest it can go is lightning-primitive-cell-factory
Setting input component to light dom doesn't help
Passing error message as type attribute - kind of works, however we are not calling report validity. We probably could on render callback.

Is there any proper way around it?
I'm thinking of some kind of subscribe/unsubscribe function passed in as parameter and called in connected/disconnected Callback.
